# Shortcut to change which statement is executed next

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

When debugging in Visual Studio, I can change the line of next execution by dragging the yellow arrow to the desired line.

Is it possible to put the cursor on a line and use a shortcut to do this instead of dragging?

[image]

Comment: you can breakpoint on that line?

Comment: @RonaldEstacion: A breakpoint would execute up to the breakpoint. In VS you can effectively skip code by moving the arrow. As the screenshot suggests, this may have unintended consequences (uninitialised values, ...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm using Visual Studio 2008 at the moment, but this can be done by right-clicking on the source and selecting "Set Next Statement" from the popup menu.  I would be surprised if this has been removed from VS2010.

If that's not short enough for you, you can go into "Tools" -> "Customise" and set up a keyboard shortcut to the "Debug.SetNextStatement" command.  On my current setup (perhaps not the default), you can press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd>.

Comment: Excellent, easy when you know where to look- it's Ctrl+Shift+F10. Thank you.